# Efficient way of shuffling data randomly and then splitting it into training and test set?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm working on a code of python that is about machine learning where i have to randomly shuffle the 100000 samples and the split data into training and test set. I have stored data into two numpy arrays. If I use following command it is too time consuming.

```
c=zip(a,b)
np.random.shuffle(c)
a,b = (*c)
```

where `a` and `b` are two numpy arrays. Is there any efficient way to shuffle data randomly and then split it into training and test set? Can some one please suggest a python code that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the function `train_test_split` from [scikit learn's cross-validation feature](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) for this purpose.

Comment: I don't want to use scikit. I have to use simple python. Moreover i want to split data only in 2 parts training and test set.

Comment: If you please suggest some link that is using simple python commands to perform this shuffling and splitting, i will be thankful